# Django ModelChoiceField get choice of connected user

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I created a forms.ModelChoiceField that contains items on my database, but it show all the users' data. I only want to show data of the connected user! Thanks for helping.

PS: I don't need to create a models.Form because I don't want to edit or update the data.

views.py

```
def sms(request):
    form2 = ListDataForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = ListDataForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            message = form2.cleaned_data["message"]
            print(message)

    else:
        form2  = ListDataForm(request=request)
    return render(request, "data_list/sms.html", {"form2": form2})
```

#### models.py

```py
class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    site = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=THE_SITE)
    content_list = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

#### forms.py

```py
class ListDataForm(forms.Form):

    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    listdata = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=List.objects.all())
```

Instead of `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=List.objects.all())` I wrote `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=List.objects.filter(author=request.user))` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that the `queryset` value is executed on class creation, that is, when you first fire up the Python interpreter and load all the Django stuff. The `request` object is not created here, but once you start getting requests from users.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), you can do it at class instantiation instead, setting the `queryset` parameter to `None` and writing

#### forms.py

```py
class ListDataForm(forms.Form):
  ...
  listdata = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)
  ...

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if request:
      user = request.user
      self.fields['listdata'].queryset = List.objects.filter(author=user)
```

Then, in your view, create this form as follows

#### views.py

```py
def form_view(request):
  ...
  form = ListDataForm(request=request)
  ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it not working.. it say ```user = request.user AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute user```

Comment: @tiberhockey you need to add the `request=request` argument when you build the form in your view. maybe post the corresponding views.py part in the question so it's easier to help you

Comment: yes i added the ```request=request```, and yes i just added my views.py in the post!

Comment: @tiberhockey just fixed the code! also I think the first line     form2 = ListDataForm() is unnecessary? since you'll be assigning the form variable anyways in the ifs. also add the request=request to your second form2 constructor, the one inside the if

Answer (score 1):

1. **Use `get_queryset`**

   ```
   class ListDataForm(forms.Form):

       message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
       listdata = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=get_queryset)

       def get_queryset(request):
           return List.objects.filter(author=request.user)
   ```

   2. Pass `request` as a argument when you will call Form.

      ```
      def your_view(request):
          ...YOUR LOGIC...
          form = ListDataForm(request)
          ...YOUR LOGIC...
      ```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but I did what you said, and it give me this error ```self._queryset = None if queryset is None else queryset.all()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error stacktrace, It might be this error generated from another location.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) the correct way to restrict the queryset for ModelChoiceFields is as below.

```
# in your form
class ListDataForm(forms.Form):    
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    listdata = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=List.objects.all())

def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user:
        listdata = self.fields['listdata']
        listdata.queryset = listdata.queryset.filter(author=user)


# in your view
...
form = ListDataForm(data, ..., user=request.user)
```